# Why this error keeps showing with my code?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, outlook

Im having this error and I cannot find how to solve it. This is the code:

```
Sub SendUniqueEmails()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim RecipientEmail As String
    Dim CCEmails As String
    Dim AttachmentPath As String
    Dim SubjectText As String
    Dim BodyText As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Initialize Outlook
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    
    'Define the range of cells with data (rows with data in column B)
    Set Rng = Range("B2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(x1Up).Row)
    
    'Loop through each row in the range
    For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    
    'Get information from the current row
    RecipientEmail = Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
    CCEmails = Rng.Cells(i, 2).Value
    SubjectText = Rng.Cells(i, 4).Value
    BodyText = Rng.Cells(i, 5).Value
    AttachmentPath = Rng.Cells(i, 3).Value
    
    'Create a new email
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = RecipientEmail
        .CC = CCEmails
        .Subject = SubjectText
        .Body = BodyText

    If AttachmentPath <> "" Then .Attachments.Add AttachmentPath
    End If
    
    'Send the email
    .Send
    End With
    
    'Release memory
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next i
    
    'Close Outlook
    OutApp.Session.Logoff
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    'Confirmation message
    MsgBox "Emails have been sent succesfully.", vbInformation
      
    
    
End Sub
```

Just help me with this vba code

Comment: Did you forget to include the error message and indicate which line of code throws it?

Comment: A classic typo here on SO! `End(x1Up).Row` >> `End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: ...and another example of why always using `Option Explicit` can save you many headaches